# Error with DLL functions in mfc

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mfc

I made a small application, in which I am loading a DLL in Init Instance of application class. The mentioned code below is running properly but in release mode it is crashing. I used Visual Studio an DLL is in Debug and Release folder of the application.

```
typedef char BufType[4095];
typedef int (*QuickLicenseRT)(BufType);

BufType             Buf;
QuickLicenseRT      pQuickLicense;
HINSTANCE           QL_Lib; 
char*               Message;
int                 i, BufSize;


BOOL CDemo::InitInstance()
{

INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);

InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

CWinApp::InitInstance();

QL_Lib = LoadLibrary(_T("QuickLicenseRuntime.dll"));
pQuickLicense = (QuickLicenseRT)GetProcAddress(QL_Lib, "QuickLicenseRT");

Message = "ABC";
BufSize = strlen(Message);

for(i=0; i<BufSize; i++)
    Buf[i]= Message[i];

Buf[BufSize] = 0;

MessageBox(NULL, _T("before pQuickLicense (Buf)"), _T("Message"), MB_OK);
(pQuickLicense)(Buf); // here it is crashing
MessageBox(NULL, _T("after pQuickLicense (Buf)"), _T("Message"), MB_OK);
ResponseMessage = Buf;

return TRUE;
```

}

I put some message boxes after some statements.   I noticed that at (pQuickLicense)(Buf), it is crashing. after loading QuickLicenseRuntime.dll, I got the address of function. I am not getting where it is wrong.

Thank You

Comment: Always check the result of your `LoadLibrary()` `GetProcAddress()` calls -- if they are not NULL, then the crash is in the `QuickLicenseRT()` logic (in the DLL), you may need to build some optional diagnostic logging to see where it crashes; one of the main differences between debug and release builds is pointer initialization...

Answer (score 1):

`Buf[BufSize] = 0;` already writes out of the Buf area theoretically damaging pQuickLicense -- practically it should not do harm because of padding. `Buf[BufSize-1] = '\0';` would be more appropriate.

You could also amend `typedef int (*QuickLicenseRT)(BufType);` to define the calling conventions, i.e. __cdecl or FAR PASCAL. Using the wrong calling convention could corrupt your data memory.

Generally, your programming style could benefit from contemplating some basic knowledge about C++, i.e. Kerningham&Ritchie "Programming in C".

Comment: Given the code logic, `Buf[BufSize-1]='\0'` will erroneously truncate the string. Regardless of that, since `BufSize` is deduced from unrelated data, using `BufSize` or `BufSize-1` as the index is equally wrong. A dynamically sized array, like `std::vector` would solve all issues. The missing calling convention, however, would be a prime candidate for a crash. The function pointer type should be available through the header file accompanying the library.

Comment: @Girish: You edited the code in the question using strlen instead of sizeof, confusing me for a minute. The new code ```Message = "ABC";
BufSize = strlen(Message); Buf[BufSize] = 0;``` just writes a '\0' character where it already is because ```strlen()``` just counts the characters till a null character is found. If you really need to initialize the buffer, ```try Buf[0] = 0 or memset(Buf, 0, sizeof(Buf));```. If you only want to copy the string, the single line ```strcpy(Buf, Message);``` is sufficient.

Comment: This is incorrect. The loop copying the characters has a termination condition of `i<BufSize`, essentially stopping right **before** the zero terminator. `Buf[BufSize]=0` is therefore mandatory. Obviously, `strcpy` is easier to use, since it already deals with the zero terminator. It's not immune to buffer overruns, though.

Comment: @IInspectable: You are missing that BufSize (3) is derived from strlen(Buf), assuming a null char at Buf[3].

Comment: I am well aware that the **source** string has a zero terminator. However, the buffer copy doesn't, and `Buf[BufSize]=0` is mandatory. `Buf` is a local object, and thus not zero-initialized. This is not an object with static storage duration (which would be zero-initialized). EDIT: I had **assumed** that `Buf` were a local object. It isn't (for whatever reason), and `Buf[BufSize]=0` is not required.

Comment: Well, you are right. Maybe I was too confused by the edited question.